# How can I get the primary key index prefix length from information_schema in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, key, information-schema

Let us suppose I have a table created as follows:

```
create table `test_table` (
  `col1` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`(16))
);
```

Now, suppose I have a script that is examining the schema, looking for information about primary keys.  How can that script find the index prefix length (16 in the above example) without parsing the output of `show create table`?  This information is not in `information_schema.key_column_usage` (in MySQL 5.1, anyway), but is it somewhere else in information_schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [information_schema.STATISTICS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/statistics-table.html) table (`SUB_PART` field) -

```
SELECT
  TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, SUB_PART
FROM
  information_schema.STATISTICS
```

or

[SHOW INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-index.html) statement.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified table engine, so I assume InnoDB. For your question - it is impossible to get index size because of the way InnoDB stores index data. Here is a MySQL bug reported with your issue, see the response at the bottom of the page: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57192 :

> This is by design. Table data in InnoDB are stored in the index
>   structure of primary key (explicit or implicit). So, primary key is
>   data and there is no need to report its size as (secondary) index
>   size.
>
> Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb.html, for example:
>
> "InnoDB stores user data in clustered indexes to reduce I/O for common
>   queries based on primary keys."

Comment: Since primary key implies unique, I'm thinking this might not be only InnoDB where that value is irrelevant. However, I have noted that even for InnoDB, the value specified in the CREATE statement is stored and reported by SHOW CREATE TABLE. I suppose a tool might want to report that just for whatever's sake.